# Add custom UIView in UINavigationbar's title view

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, xib

I want to add custom UIView in UINavigation's `titleview`. The problem is, the width of my custom view is 320 and it don't auto fit in `UINavigation's` `titleview`. Some portion of my view gets out from the r.h.s boundary.

In following image, bottom view show the whole length of custom view, this is just for description purpose here. Actual situation is little different. I am designing in `xib` files. `UIView` is designed in different file and used in some `UIViewController` by programatically like `self.previousNavTitle = self.customView;`

But I am getting some portion of custom view hidden. Please guide me in this regard. Thanks.

[image: UIView in UiNavigation's titlebar]

Answer (score 0):

Try below code snippet

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = self.customView;
```